# Using libraries compiled with different compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, debugging

I have to write Qt-based application which will be using [CTK](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Main_Page) library and some widgets from [Slicer](http://www.slicer.org/) - all compiled in Debug mode in VS2008, also needs Qt 4.8.4.

Question: is it possible to develop and debug my application on another machine with Qt 4.8.4 and VS2010 installed, without any problems?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the interfaces of the libraries are. In particular VS states that they do break binary compatibility among different versions of the C++ standard library *for debugging and optimization purposes*.

If the interfaces are pure Qt, you might get along (I would check with the Qt people), *but* beware, if this fail you are going to have a miserable time debugging. Binary incompatibilities are one of the harder things to figure out as the view the debugger gives you of an object does not necessarily represent what the code is using it as.

I'd recommend against this, and suggest that you install the same version of the compiler (and compile with the same flags)